# how to create progress bar using nsDialogs?

Tags: installation, progress-bar, nsis, nsdialogs

I want to create a progress bar for my installer which will show the progress of my installation process.I know a command as ${NSD_CreateProgressBar} in nsDialogs to create a progress bar in nsis script. But I am unaware of how to use it and how to invoke the same in my script. Any kind of help in respective subject will be appreciated...

Comment: What exactly do you want to do on this custom page? Normally you do most of the actual installing in sections and they execute on the instfiles page

Comment: Actually I want to perform my installation process on that page and show the same using progressbar on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [**this resource**](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsDialogs_FAQ) and play around with it. Look for "***How to Control a Progress Bar control (using absolute values)***" OR "***How to Control a Progress Bar control (using step values)***"

Comment: How to create progress bar from the start of Execwait function till the end of Execwait in NSIS?